# PHP timezone from php.ini not being applied

Tags: php, date, timezone

For some reason the `date()` function is not outputting the timezone-adjusted date/time. In debugging this, I found a weird disparity. My timezone is defined in `php.ini` as `America/New_York`. When I call this:

`echo ini_get('date.timezone');`

I get `America/New_York`, which is what I expect. However, when I call this:

`echo date_default_timezone_get();`

I get `UTC`. It seems this is responsible for the `date()` method returning the time in the UTC timezone. Why is this happening? How do I make PHP respect the timezone found in `php.ini`?

**UPDATE**

I am ultimately just trying to get the timezone-adjusted time from `date('Y-m-d G:i:s')`. Since my timezone is set in php.ini, how do I get the correct date/time from `date()`?

Comment: Respect? According to the manual documentation of the function in question - [`date_default_timezone_get()`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_get) - there is no determinate 1:1 relation between the ini setting and but only - and only if used - between that and `date_default_timezone_set()` (the setting counterpart). So what are you asking here? Just that?

Comment: all I care about is when I call ```date('Y-m-d G:i:s')``` I want the timezone-adjusted date/time.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I understood you. You probably should try if it now works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the meaning of *respect* right in your question, you're wondering that [`date_default_timezone_get()`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_get) is not returning the ini setting. You can change that by calling this line before the get operation:

```
date_default_timezone_set(ini_get('date.timezone'));
```

See as well *Example #2 Getting the abbreviation of a timezone* from the manual which covers that:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date_default_timezone_get() . ' => ' . date('e') . ' => ' . date('T');
```

The above example will output:

```
America/Los_Angeles => America/Los_Angeles => PST
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I don't care about ```date_default_timezone_get()``` per se, all I care about is when I call ```date('Y-m-d G:i:s')``` I want the timezone-adjusted date/time.

Comment: Well, you care about `date()`, right. That's why I added an example in the answer that shows how `date()` is influenced by that. You might just have it overlooked otherwise I don't understand why you comment that way. Just let me know if this still doesn't answer your question.